# How to split the large text file(32 GB) using C#

Tags: c#

I tried to split the file about 32GB using the below code but I got the `memory exception`.

Please suggest me to split the file using `C#`.

```
string[] splitFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\\JKS\\ImportGenius\\0.txt");

int cycle = 1;
int splitSize = Convert.ToInt32(txtNoOfLines.Text);
var chunk = splitFile.Take(splitSize);
var rem = splitFile.Skip(splitSize);

while (chunk.Take(1).Count() > 0)
{
    string filename = "file" + cycle.ToString() + ".txt";
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
    {
        foreach (string line in chunk)
        {
    sw.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
    chunk = rem.Take(splitSize);
    rem = rem.Skip(splitSize);
    cycle++;
}
```

Comment: Thats easy to fix. Just buy more than 32GB RAM and you will be able to read the whole file in memory.

Comment: I guess you would need a StreamReader

Comment: You just read the entire 32GB text file into memory at once, which is completely unethical.

Comment: @siidheesh ,It's a crime against humanity!

Comment: @Stilgar: Actually, you would need more than 64 GB, as a char is two bytes.

Comment: Depends on the encoding but it may in fact be the case if the file is ASCII or UTF-8 with the latin subset. Also keep in mind that he will need 64 bit version of the application!

Comment: @Stilgar In .NET, strings are always UTF-16 in memory, no matter the encoding used to store them in the file.

Comment: @KooKiz I know but if the file is UTF-16 on the disc then it will still be the same size in memory. He will only need 64GB if the file uses single byte encoding.

Comment: Actually 64GB of memory might not be enough, continuous memory is needed to allocate each line and the array. RAM is not needed (see swap/pagefile). http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx

Comment: Are all the lines unique?  Or are there some duplication's?  Give us some sample data.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, to start with you need to use `File.ReadLines` (assuming you're using .NET 4) so that it doesn't try to read the whole thing into memory. Then I'd just keep calling a method to spit the "next" however many lines to a new file:

```
int splitSize = Convert.ToInt32(txtNoOfLines.Text);
using (var lineIterator = File.ReadLines(...).GetEnumerator())
{
    bool stillGoing = true;
    for (int chunk = 0; stillGoing; chunk++)
    {
        stillGoing = WriteChunk(lineIterator, splitSize, chunk);
    }
}

...

private static bool WriteChunk(IEnumerator<string> lineIterator,
                               int splitSize, int chunk)
{
    using (var writer = File.CreateText("file " + chunk + ".txt"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < splitSize; i++)
        {
            if (!lineIterator.MoveNext())
            {
                return false;
            }
            writer.WriteLine(lineIterator.Current);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Jon.

Comment: But while trying to use your code it showing that for Iterators "Could not found directive or assembly reference". Please help me to rectify this

Comment: @Jaffer: Sorry, typo - that should have been `IEnumerator<T>`. Fixed.

Comment: Hi Jon. Still facing the problem. While calling the WriteChunk method it showing as the method has invalid arguments.

Comment: @Jaffer: Try now - I've edited the `using` statement in the calling code.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I will try and let u know.

Answer (score 8):

Do not read *immediately* all lines into an array, but use [StremReader.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) method, like:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"E:\\JKS\\ImportGenius\\0.txt")) 
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
       var fileLine = sr.ReadLine();
       //do something with line
    }
}
```

Comment: To be nitpicking, a line could be > 32 GB

Comment: @Guillaume: Considering that OP's uses ReadAllLines I *suppose* the format of the file is that one I suppose to be, thow devided by lines, and not one sinlgle big line.

Comment: and we agree that it might be an issue if the file doesn't comes from a trusted peer or if the format is not well defined. Moreover, copying a file line by line is inefficient. Reusing a buffer (say 32K) would improve a lot. This might also be an issue on files > 32 GB. Still, your solution might be sufficient for Jaffer needs.

Comment: @Guillaume: With very big file MemoryMapped files are definitely good choice too. But the point is that there is *always* a space to do something better, no doubts. The thing is that if you're going to deal with memory chunks, you have to deal with **at least** with *Encoding* and *rewrite completely string parsing procedure*, which *may* be avoided with this solution, In this way you *may* gian much more benefit in develeopment then focusing on the *concrete* execution flow.

Comment: I was thinking about ReadBlock, it manages Encoding : http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.textreader.readblock

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> File.ReadAllLines
> ```

That will read the *whole file into memory*.

To work with large files you need to only read what you need now into memory, and then throw that away as soon as you have finished with it.

A better option would be [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readlines.aspx) which returns a lazy enumerator, data is only read into memory as you get the next line from the enumerator. Providing you avoid multiple enumerations (eg. don't use `Count()`) only parts of the file will be read.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of reading all the file at once using `File.ReadAllLines`, use `File.ReadLines` in a foreach loop to read the lines as needed.

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"E:\\JKS\\ImportGenius\\0.txt"))
{
    // Do something
}
```

**Edit:** On an unrelated note, you don't have to escape your backslashes when prefixing the string with a '@'. So either write `"E:\\JKS\\ImportGenius\\0.txt"` or `@"E:\JKS\ImportGenius\0.txt"`, but `@"E:\\JKS\\ImportGenius\\0.txt"` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are reading the entire file's content into memory at once with `File.ReadAllLines()`. What you need to do is open a FileStream with `File.OpenRead()` and read/write smaller chunks.

Edit: Actually for your case ReadLine is obviously better. See other answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [StreamReade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)r to read the file, write with a StreamWriter.